# In Golang testcontainers Rabbit MQ image got context deadline exceeded on start

Tags: docker, go, rabbitmq, testcontainers

I use Rabbit MQ container for testing my application and sometimes I have got a strange error: context deadline exceeded (more in picture) [testcontainers error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrlGA.png)

I create a container like this

```golang
func createTestMQContainer(ctx context.Context) testcontainers.Container {
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Name:         "my-service-test-mq",
        Image:        "rabbitmq:3",
        ExposedPorts: []string{mqTestPort + "/tcp"},
        WaitingFor:   wait.ForLog("Server startup complete; 3 plugins started."),
    }
    mqContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return mqContainer
}
```

This container print this logs after startup:

```
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.725300+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Running boot step rabbit_maintenance_mode_state defined by app rabbit
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.725471+00:00 [info] <0.230.0> Creating table rabbit_node_maintenance_states for maintenance mode status
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.726860+00:00 [info] <0.527.0> Resetting node maintenance status
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.756869+00:00 [info] <0.558.0> Prometheus metrics: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15692
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.757360+00:00 [info] <0.527.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
2023-11-09 14:16:02 2023-11-09 11:16:02.762557+00:00 [info] <0.602.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
2023-11-09 14:16:03  completed with 3 plugins.
2023-11-09 14:16:03 2023-11-09 11:16:03.070977+00:00 [info] <0.527.0> Server startup complete; 3 plugins started.
2023-11-09 14:16:03 2023-11-09 11:16:03.070977+00:00 [info] <0.527.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
2023-11-09 14:16:03 2023-11-09 11:16:03.070977+00:00 [info] <0.527.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
2023-11-09 14:16:03 2023-11-09 11:16:03.070977+00:00 [info] <0.527.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
```

If I start this only this test it will be successfull. But when I start multiple tests error will occur (with flag -p 1 also).

I try to use -p flag on test but when I have more tests it doesn't help.
Also I try to use regex for wait log but I have the same issue.

Upd. I'm stopping all my containers after test like this

```golang
func TerminateTestContainer(ctx context.Context, container testcontainers.Container) {
  if err := container.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

I don't use one container in more than one test

Comment: When do you start the container? Are you sharing the same container between 2 tests or are you creating a new container for each test with createTestMQContainer?

Comment: @silh I start the container before every test. For each test function I create a new container using this function

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/tree/main/modules/rabbitmq ?

Comment: @Arlet do you also stop it after the test? the reason I am asking is because it's not clear from the given example code. If you don't, then you need to do that, because otherwise the port will be occupied by the container from the previous test.

Comment: @silh Yes, I forgot to add this code snippet. I updated my post for this. When I start tests I can see running container with logs that my program were expecting but testcontainers ignored this logs

Comment: @Marrow父, no I use only container request that I saw in the quick start guide. I will try this example, thank you

Comment: @Arlet would be good to have the code for the full test (minimal reproduction scenario) and full logs with the error in them and logs from the container. It's a bit difficult to understand what the problem might be with the given information.

Comment: @Arlet  Personally, I'd recommend not starting the testcontainer in each test... it will mean that each and every test will be waiting for the testcontainer to start.  You might find it better to start a single testconatiner for all of your tests (utilising `func TestMain(m *testing.M)` )- which would, of course, mean ensuring that tests aren't run in parallel and probably purging queues/topics at the start of each test.

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of `mqTestPort`? Is it a using a fixed port format, like "5671", or is it using "5671:5671"? The latter will result in binding a fixed port in the Docker host, which could cause a port conflict if that container is reused in multiple tests. If using the first one will bind to a random port that could be accessed using Testcontainers' APIs, like `MappedPort`.

Regarding the quickstart guide, you mean [this](https://golang.testcontainers.org/quickstart/)? It is using Redis as example, but each technology has its own particularities. I'd go with the Go module for RabbitMQ, as suggested by @Marrow父, please take a look at its docs: https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/rabbitmq/. The module includes methods to get the different URLs for RabbitMQ, please see https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/rabbitmq/#amqp-urls